# Can' t open Visual Studio solution on another PC

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a wpf project in Visual Studio with a `.MDF` database file, created using built-in SQL Server extension in Visual Studio. When I move the solution to another PC with the same version of Visual Studio, I get a message saying that the `.MDF` file can't be opened, so the program doesn't start.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

The error is:

`An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file <File Name> failed`

Comment: what is the `AttachDbFilename`? can you provide some relevant code? and please edit your question. The title is totally irrelevant to your actual problem.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server **Express** edition installed on that other PC?? That's a pre-requisite to using a "free-floating" `.mdf` which should be dynamically attached to your application

Comment: AttachDBFilename shows the Path to the actual MDF file on the First PC, than i edited It with the Path updated in the new PC. I don' t have SQL express installed standalone, i have the extension in visual studio, likes in the first PC.

Comment: Never use the MDF file directly.  Connect to the server and use the database name (not the file mdf).  the server know the location of the file which is part of the attach information.

Comment: Visual studio does not open database files. SQL server does. you need a version of SQL

Comment: If you want to use `.mdf` file - you **MUST HAVE** SQL Server **Express** installed - the "extensions" from Visual Studio aren't enough! You **MUST INSTALL** SQL Server **Express** - it's a **mandatory pre-requisite** ....